# Convert ImagePath in DocumentDirectory to NSURL Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using following code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSURL *myUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.selectedRing.ringThumbNailImagePath];
[Utilities responseDataFromURL:myUrl completionBlock:^(NSData *fileData, NSError *err)
{
    if (err != nil)
    {
        [self.indicator stopAnimating];
        [Utilities errorDisplay:@""];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.igo"];
        NSLog(@"FilePath: %@", filePath);

        if ([fileData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES])
        {
            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);    
            NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", filePath]];
            NSLog(@"JPG path %@", filePath);
```

filePath is

```
Users/umar/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/B45223CF-B437-4617-A02D-DCA91C965A5A/Documents/Test.igo
```

however i get Nil igImageHookFile NSURL. What is wrong?

Comment: @myhammad at list give response about answer...!!! that is helpful or not :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fileURLWithPath` for converting your Path of Document Directory to NSURL like this in piece of code:

```
NSURL *myImagePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]; //here filePath is your document directory full path with extantionm
```

#### For Example:

```
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.igo"];
        NSLog(@"FilePath: %@", filePath);

        if ([fileData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES])
        {
            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);   

            NSURL *igImageHookFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]; 

            NSLog(@"URL from path %@", igImageHookFile);
```

**OUTPUT of path URL something like this:-**

```
file://localhost/Users/umar/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/B45223CF-B437-4617-A02D-DCA91C965A5A/Documents/Test.igo
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[Request stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: ? not op's problem and this answer seems totally unrelated -- taken from something else

Comment: question is url is not nil after setting path. so this can be a solution. that's what i thought.